# Why Kalki Avatar will come at the end of the yuga not in between like all other Avatars of Vishnu?

Tags: avatars, kali-yuga, kalki

As there are 4 Yugas.

How many Avatars in each yuga? Why different in number of Avatars?

Why only one avatar in Kali Yug?

Like lord Rama and lord Krishna have come in between of those Yugas. But why Kalki Avatar will come at the end?

It is said that whenever Papa increases then an Avatar comes to restore the Dharma. And now also in Kali Yug many Papa are done by many Ravana and Kansas from each family. In Ramayan there was only one Sita was abducted by one Ravan, in Kali Yug also many Sita are there who are abducted by many Ravans.

so Is it not the time for Vishnu to take an Avatar to restore the Dharma?

If Kalki Avatar comes at the end of Kali Yug and start of Satya Yug and no people of Kali Yug will have experience with this Avatar, then can we say Kalki is not an Avatar of Kali Yug but of Satya Yug And no Avatars in Kaliyuga?

Comment: Kalki is Kali Yuga avatar only. Kalki will incarnate in the end of the Kali Yuga when the Adharma is at its peak See my answer for a similar question [What is the apex of Adharma](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/21052/5212) and [When will the Kalki avatar be born?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2012/5212).

Comment: @NogShine "Kalki will incarnate in the end of the Kali Yuga when the Adharma is at its peak" LOL. Like Dharma is at the peak now or there is no need of Avatar now. I think Avatar comes not because to establish dharma but because of Niyati.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**How many Avatars in each yuga? Why different in number of Avatars?**

As Lord's incarnations are infinite, so hard to say but if you believe only in 24 or 10 incarnations then this can be answered. Number of Avataras depends on incidents, in previous Yugas, Dharma was more but mighter Asuras were also more.

This is partially answered in [What is chronological timeline (in Manvantara and Mahayuga) of Lord Vishnu incarnations?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21692/what-is-chronological-timeline-in-manvantara-and-mahayuga-of-lord-vishnu-incar/21714#21714)

**Why only one avatar in Kali Yug?**

Buddha avatar already happened in Kali Yuga and Kalki is yet to be happened.

**Like lord Rama and lord Krishna have come in between of those Yugas. But why Kalki Avatar will come at the end?**

Wrong, Lord Krishna incarnated at the end of 28th Dwapara Yuga or in the conjunction time of Dwapara and Kali Yuga to be more correct.

Kaliyuga started from king Parikshit who was next king after Yudhisthira. *- as per Bhagvata Purana*

**So Is it not the time for Vishnu to take an Avatar to restore the Dharma?**

Opinion based question. May be the pot of sins yet to be filled.

This is partially answered in [What is the apex of Adharma](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/21052/5212) and [When will the Kalki avatar be born?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2012/5212).

**If Kalki Avatar comes at the end of Kali Yug and start of Satya Yug and no people of Kali Yug will have experience with this Avatar, then can we say Kalki is not an Avatar of Kali Yug but of Satya Yug And no Avatars in Kaliyuga?**

One avatar (Budhdha) has already incarnated. And if you believe in this theory then you should consider Lord Krishna as an avatara of Kali Yuga.

Comment: Super answer YDS!