# Is the influence of current materialistic nature a feature of this Kaliyuga?

Tags: puranas, yuga, kali-yuga

Is the influence of current materialistic life with technology a feature of this Kaliyuga? Did this happen before i.e., during previous Kaliyugas? Did Indian kings alone rule the world in previous Kaliyugas?

Comment: A suggestion. Be careful while talking about countries, using words like "we". Western and attributing things to them.You should avoid words like "we" here and specify whom you are talking about. This website is based in America. We are not an Indian website to talk just about India and the users are not only Indians. The main audience are westerners. Also, use proper tags.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma, ok. My question iz this. You know how this yuga is functioning.  Iam asking is this Kaliyuga different ? Or did we have this type before?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma edited the question as per your suggestion

Comment: About technology and materialism.. answered already in [What about the technology of the previous Kali Yugas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9367/5212) , [What is the apex of adharma?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14870/5212). See those questions and answers. There are other features of this yuga said in other Q&A too (which I didn't find).

Comment: I think sages /celestial beings/self realized persons incarnate in this world to teach us truth and highest knowledge. Every age such people descend and leave us message via scriptures. Thus there's nothing new in discovery. Their message is that to discover who are we and we must act accordingly. @UdayKrishna