# How many kaliyugas completed till now and every kaliyuga kalki will come?

Tags: bhagavata-purana, brahma-sutras, manvantara, kalpa, kalki-purana

Since Brahma age is completed 50 and 51 is running which means one day brahma is equal to one kalpa and one kalpa equal to 14 manvantaras and one manvantara equals to 71 mahayugas and each mahayuga consists of 4 yugas in each yuga a  incarnation is formed to kill evil but present kaliyugas which is  also happened in different manvantars and mahayugas  have the same technolgy and cultural standards of people like present kaliyuga???  And there also same kalki incarnation will come to end this kaliyuga???

Comment: Related https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/28769/is-the-influence-of-current-materialistic-nature-a-feature-of-this-kaliyuga 

https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9367/what-about-the-technology-of-the-previous-kali-yugas

Answer (score 1):

I actually had a same doubt after I came to know that Ramayana happened in 24th Mahayuga but not since then and we are in 28th Mahayuga. After going through the above shared links and few more links I understood that all Lord Vishnu's incarnation are not happening in the same Mahayuga. Hence, Kalki avatar might not have been in the previous Kaliyuga and it might be a different Lord Vishnu's avatar responsible to restore Dharma in previous Kaliyuga. I even had a doubt if Lord Hanuman is still present in this Mahayuga as Ramayana happened in 24th Mahayuga. However, I came to know that Mahabhartha happened in the current Mahayuga which means that Lord Hanuman is still present on earth and will remain on earth on many Mahayugas until there are people chanting Lord Ram's name. There is another possibility that Ramayana and Mahabhartha happens in every Mahayuga and the traces of that was somehow destroyed in this Mahayuga. The reason I believe in this latter theory is that there was a story when Lord Ram asks Hanuman ji to fetch his ring from the Nag loka and there Lord Hanuman finds the mountain of rings and comes to know that there has been several Lord Ram incarnated and will keep on incarnating in the future. Also, there is a Ram setu which I am not sure whether it has been here since 24th Mahayuga or it was built in 28th Mahayuga which is the current Mahayuga.